# Can we learn Sri Rudram using audio?

Tags: mantras, guru

I am aware that we need to be initiated into something like Shri Rudram or Purusha Suktam or Shri Suktam.

But, would learning them using audio files amount to getting initiated into them?

Or do we have to approach a guru in person?

Just for the record, I'm not opposed to learning it from a guru in person. I was just curious to know if it was all right.

Comment: You can go on without any guru, its all right to do it without Physical guru , if that(without physical guru) is the case you can consider Dakshinamurthy/Shri Guru Dattatreya as your guru, and continue your journey. I am sure you will get divine help.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dattatreya  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dakshinamurthy

Comment: @Yogi I think numerous Hindu scriptures say that you need to go to a physical guru.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan - Well its a matter of opinion,willingness and trust in divine guru to help you. There is all sort of corruption in physical relam but not in spiritual relam